# Jetty 7: configuring JNDI for Start.java

Tags: java, jetty, wicket, jndi

Following Wicket 1.5's lead, I'm converting a project from Jetty 6.1.25 to 7.5.0.v20110901. My existing `Start.java` contains the following setup, which I use to configure JNDI:

```
    EnvConfiguration envConfiguration = new EnvConfiguration();
    URL url = new File("src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jetty-env.xml").toURI().toURL();
    envConfiguration.setJettyEnvXml(url);

    bb.setConfigurations(new Configuration[]{new WebInfConfiguration(),
                         envConfiguration,
                         new org.mortbay.jetty.plus.webapp.Configuration(), new JettyWebXmlConfiguration(),
                         new TagLibConfiguration()});
```

Then my `jetty-env.xml` has the following:

```
<Configure class="org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">

    <New class="org.mortbay.jetty.plus.naming.Resource">
        <Arg>jdbc/myapp</Arg>
        <Arg>
            <New class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
                <Set name="driverClassName">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</Set>
                <Set name="url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/myapp?characterEncoding=utf8</Set>
                <Set name="username">username</Set>
                <Set name="password">password</Set>
            </New>
        </Arg>
    </New>

</Configure>
```

This has worked great in Jetty 6, but in 7, `org.mortbay.jetty.plus.webapp.Configuration` does not seem to exist (or perhaps I'm missing a Jar).

Can someone give me some guidance on how to configure JNDI with Jetty 7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the following into src/test/jetty/jetty-env.xml:

```
<Configure id="wac" class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.EnvEntry">
    <Arg>jdbc/mydatasource</Arg>
    <Arg>
        <New class="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource">
            <Set name="Url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydatabase?characterEncoding=utf8</Set>
            <Set name="User">username</Set>
            <Set name="Password">password</Set>
        </New>
    </Arg>
    </New>
</Configure>
```

Then modify `Start.java` to define the following properties:

```
System.setProperty("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "org.eclipse.jetty.jndi");
System.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial", "org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.InitialContextFactory");
```

And add the following configuration to the WebAppContext:

```
EnvConfiguration envConfiguration = new EnvConfiguration();
URL url = new File("src/test/jetty/jetty-env.xml").toURI().toURL();
envConfiguration.setJettyEnvXml(url);

bb.setConfigurations(new Configuration[]{ new WebInfConfiguration(), envConfiguration, new WebXmlConfiguration() });
```

Full details on my [blog](http://blog.armhold.com/2011/12/28/how-to-get-jndi-working-with-wicket-1-5-and-jetty-7-5/).

Answer (score 4):

Starting with Jetty 7, the package name was changed from `org.mortbay.jetty` to `org.eclipse.jetty`.

In addition, `org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.Configuration` was renamed in version 7.2.0 and the new name is **[`PlusConfiguration`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/7.5.4.v20111024/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/plus/webapp/PlusConfiguration.html)**. I'm guessing this was done to avoid a name clash with `org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.Configuration`.