# Java SQL DataSource Resource Configuration

Tags: java, maven-jetty-plugin

In Java Spring, I am trying to keep my database settings outside of the main app so that it can be configured on other servers with minimal effort. I am using Tomcat 7 for my production server and a Jetty server (jetty-maven-plugin version 8.1.14.v20131031) for development.

The main problem I am running into is I cannot get the working Tomcat 7 configuration to translate to Jetty using the same class (javax.sql.DataSource). I am starting with this class, opposed to a more robust one so that I am starting with something as basic as possible.

If this is a case where there is no direct translation between the two servers, or this is simply bad practice I am looking for what would be a good practice or standard.

For example, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923980/jetty-7-configuring-jndi-for-start-java) is an alternative configuration that uses a different class, and works with Jetty. (However it doesn't answer why the basic DataSource class works with Tomcat and not with Jetty.)

I have the a Resource entry in server.xml like so:

```
<Context path="/" docBase="/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/myapp" reloadable="true">
    <Resource name="mysql-dataSource" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
          url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname"
          username="dbuser"
          password="dbuser" />
</Context>
```

jetty-maven-plugin POM entry:

```
...
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>8.1.14.v20131031</version>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.29</version>
            </dependency>           
        </dependencies>         
        <configuration>
            <!-- <useProvidedScope>?</useProvidedScope> -->
            <webApp>
                <jettyEnvXml>${basedir}/jetty-env.xml</jettyEnvXml>             
            </webApp>
        </configuration>
</plugin>   
...
```

This works fine in Tomcat7.

For Jetty, I am using jetty-env.xml with the following configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" "http://jetty.eclipse.org/configure.dtd">
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <New id="ds" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
        <Arg>mysql-dataSource</Arg>
        <Arg>
            <New class="javax.sql.DataSource">
                <Set name="driverClassName">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</Set>
                <Set name="url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname</Set>
                <Set name="username">dbuser</Set>
                <Set name="password">dbuser</Set>
            </New>
        </Arg>
    </New>
</Configure>
```

With that I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Constructor: <New class="javax.sql.DataSource">...
```

Comment: I have reworded the question so that it is more focused on what I am really asking. That being, a one-to-one translation between Tomcat and Jetty configs. The answer indicated as being the same as this uses different classes (EnvEntry vs Resource, MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource vs DataSource).

Answer (score 1):

Add this

```
 <Arg></Arg>
```

above

```
<Arg>mysql-dataSource</Arg>
```

As  first "Arg" is the scope, and without it, the rest of your arguments are out of position, and are probably causing your issue.

For more information [Jetty/Howto/Configure JNDI Datasource](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_JNDI_Datasource)

**Edit :**

Have you add scope `provided` for the specific version of Jetty ?

Comment: Are you referring to "useProvidedScope"? I've tried it with True and False after adding the missing <Arg> with no luck. I'm going to update my question with my POM configuration.